# Uber-api endpoint for history is not working after authorization

Tags: uber-api

I am writing an application based on uber apis.
For that I am using 'profile history_lite request' as scope while authenticating using oauth2. After authentication I am calling endpoint:-

'https://api.uber.com/v1/history'
which gives error 401:-
 "message":"Requires at least one scope. Available scopes: ","code":"unauthorized"

But other endpoint 'https://api.uber.com/v1/products?latitude=37.7759792&longitude=-122.41823' is working.

Do I need any other permission for first endpoint to work or I am missing something?

I used python requests lib for api call which looked like:-

```
res = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)
```

and headers is a map which value is

```
{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer xxx-acces-token-xxx'}
```

Comment: I am also getting the same issue for /requests but on sandbox environment. Any solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/v1/history` (which required the `history` scope) has been deprecated and is no longer available.

`/v1.1/history` is still available and is accessed with the `history_lite` scope.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for prompt reply. Should I use v1.1 for all the endpoints?